# SQL Server 2008 - Update SQL Help Needed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

First and foremost, the SQL is handled dynamically by the server, therefore some items in my `WHERE` clause may look odd to you, please disregard these as they are not an issue.

Per my clients request, they needed to `UNION` in two other conditions to my update report (/*Patients without a Patient Visit*/) and (/*Patients without a Appointment*/). I need help adding in the patients of these two subsets into my final update query. In its present state, it's only adding in the `#Temp` patients and I need to incorporate the additional patients.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

My current SQL update -

```
DECLARE @Inactive INT
DECLARE @Active INT
DECLARE @PatientProfileId INT

SELECT
    @Inactive = MedlistsId
FROM
    Medlists
WHERE
    TableName = 'PatientProfileStatus'
    AND Code = 'I'

SELECT
    @Active = MedlistsId
FROM
    Medlists
WHERE
    TableName = 'PatientProfileStatus'
    AND Code = 'A'

CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
      PatientName VARCHAR(120) ,
      PatientProfileId INT ,
      RecentId INT ,
      Recent DATETIME
    )

INSERT  INTO #Temp
        SELECT
            dbo.FormatName(pp.Prefix , pp.First , pp.Middle , pp.Last , pp.Suffix) AS Name ,
            pp.PatientProfileId ,
            MAX(pv.PatientVisitId) AS RecentId ,
            MAX(pv.Visit) AS Recent
        FROM
            PatientVisit pv
            INNER JOIN PatientProfile pp ON pv.PatientProfileId = pp.PatientProfileId
                                            AND pp.PatientStatusMId = @Active
        WHERE
            pp.PatientProfileId IN ( SELECT
                                        a.OwnerId
                                     FROM
                                        Appointments a
                                        INNER JOIN PatientProfile pp ON a.OwnerId = pp.PatientProfileId
                                                                        AND a.ApptKind = 1
                                                                        AND pp.PatientStatusMId = @Active
                                     GROUP BY
                                        a.OwnerId ,
                                        a.ApptKind
                                     HAVING
                                        MAX(a.ApptStart) < '07/30/2005' )
        GROUP BY
            dbo.FormatName(pp.Prefix , pp.First , pp.Middle , pp.Last , pp.Suffix) ,
            pp.PatientProfileId
        HAVING
            MAX(pv.Visit) < '07/30/2005' 

/*Patients without a Appointment*/

IF 1 = 1 
    INSERT  INTO #Temp
            SELECT
                dbo.FormatName(pp.Prefix , pp.First , pp.Middle , pp.Last , pp.Suffix) AS Name ,
                pp.PatientProfileId ,
                NULL AS RecentId ,
                NULL AS Recent
            FROM
                PatientProfile pp
                LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM Medlists WHERE TableName = 'PatientProfileStatus' ) ml1 ON pp.PatientStatusMId = ml1.MedlistsId
                LEFT JOIN Appointments a ON a.Ownerid = pp.PatientProfileId
                                            AND a.ApptKind = 1
                LEFT JOIN PatientVisit pv ON a.PatientVisitId = pv.PatientVisitId
            WHERE
                ml1.Code = 'A'
                AND a.ownerid IS NULL
                AND --Filter on Age
                (
                  ((
                     '-1' = '-1'
                     AND '40' = '125'
                   )
                  OR ( CAST(( DATEDIFF(DAY , pp.Birthdate , GETDATE()) / 365.25 ) AS INT) BETWEEN ( '-1' ) AND ( '40' ) ))
                )

/*Patients without a Patient Visit*/

IF 0 = 1 
    INSERT  INTO #Temp
            SELECT
                dbo.FormatName(pp.Prefix , pp.First , pp.Middle , pp.Last , pp.Suffix) AS Name ,
                pp.PatientProfileId ,
                NULL AS RecentId ,
                NULL AS Recent
            FROM
                PatientProfile pp
                LEFT JOIN PatientVisit pv ON pv.PatientProfileid = pp.PatientProfileid
                LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM Medlists WHERE TableName = 'PatientProfileStatus' ) ml1 ON pp.PatientStatusMId = ml1.MedlistsId
            WHERE
                ml1.Code = 'A'
                AND pv.patientprofileid IS NULL
                AND --Filter on Age
                (
                  ((
                     '-1' = '-1'
                     AND '40' = '125'
                   )
                  OR ( CAST(( DATEDIFF(DAY , pp.Birthdate , GETDATE()) / 365.25 ) AS INT) BETWEEN ( '-1' ) AND ( '40' ) ))
                )   

DECLARE curPatient CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY LOCAL
FOR
    SELECT
        t.PatientProfileId
    FROM
        #Temp t
        JOIN PatientProfile pp ON t.PatientProfileId = pp.PatientProfileId
        JOIN PatientVisit pv ON pp.PatientProfileId = pv.PatientProfileId
                                AND pv.PatientVisitId = t.RecentId
    WHERE
        --Filter on Age
        (
          ((
             '-1' = '-1'
             AND '40' = '125'
           )
          OR ( CAST(( DATEDIFF(DAY , pp.Birthdate , GETDATE()) / 365.25 ) AS INT) BETWEEN ( '-1' ) AND ( '40' ) ))
        )

OPEN curPatient
FETCH NEXT FROM curPatient INTO @PatientProfileId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN  

        UPDATE
            PatientProfile
        SET 
            PatientStatusMId = @Inactive ,
            pstatus = 'I'
        FROM
            PatientProfile P
            INNER JOIN #Temp t ON t.PatientProfileID = P.PatientProfileID
        WHERE
            p.PatientProfileId = @PatientProfileId 


        FETCH NEXT FROM curPatient INTO @PatientProfileId 
    END 

CLOSE curPatient
DEALLOCATE curPatient   

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: ... Your table `MedLists` appears to be multi-domain (given the `tablename` column), and probably ought to be broken up.  Is there something I'm not aware of, or would `DATEDIFF(YEAR, pp.birthdate, GETDATE())` return a person's age in years (note that your current method, dividing by 365.25, won't always give the correct results).  You seem to be joining to a lot of tables for information you don't end up using - why, and could the references be eliminated (`patientName` isn't used, for example)?  Spinning through a cursor this way is **not** the most efficient way to update a table.

Answer (score 0):

This will limit to patients WITH an appointment

```
LEFT JOIN Appointments a 
       ON a.Ownerid = pp.PatientProfileId
      AND a.ApptKind = 1
```

This will limit to patients WITH a Visit

```
LEFT JOIN PatientVisit pv 
       ON pv.PatientProfileid = pp.PatientProfileid
```

Try

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Appointments a 
           ON a.Ownerid = pp.PatientProfileId
          AND a.ApptKind = 1
Where a.Ownerid is null


LEFT OUTER JOIN PatientVisit pv 
       ON pv.PatientProfileid = pp.PatientProfileid
Where pv.PatientProfileid is null
```